# Bad perfomance of app with Framelayout with background

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout(container for fragments) inside activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/general_top_info_main"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<include
    layout="@layout/progressbar"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cont_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"></FrameLayout>
```

This works fine.

But when im adding background to FrameLayout app starts freezing.
I need add background in container because all fragments have the same, and i dont want to add background to all of them.

So how can i add background.

Comment: What does it look like when you add the background to the container? Are the backgrounds still set on the Fragments, or have you already removed them?

Comment: fragments with transparent background.

Comment: What are you using for a background that is causing the app to "freeze".

Comment: im adding background in xml : background = "@drawable/image"

Comment: as I said - just reduce image size

Comment: ok, i will try.

Comment: if an answer is correct just check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just reduce your background picture size. It's known issue. An example: Your pic has 1920x1080 size, but you need reduce it on (an example) 800x600.

Comment: @Roman if you use picture for your background, so you need reduce it size. If not, so give us code of your includes.

Comment: Or you can put on xxhdpi folder.